# PeachPie WordPress with MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, php, .net, asp.net-core, peachpie

Peach Pie runs WordPress on .Net Core.  Does Peach Pie have a method/service to use a SQL Server connection string to Run SQL Server as its backend database to run WordPress within Peach Pie?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing(thus finding your post), turns out there's a Wordpress fork called Project Nami https://projectnami.org/ That supports Wordpress with MS SQL. I'm planning to try it out myself tonight ..